# Visibilty of inserted record in FORALL Bulk statement

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g, bulkinsert

I have 2 arrays which I will be using to use with FORALL to insert/update. I am not sure if i can use "MERGE" statement with FORALL so I am using two arrays.

While populating data in array, I check if its already in db. If it is, i put the populated data in an array which is meant to be updated otherwise it goes to insert array.

```
TYPE T_TABLE IS TABLE OF TABLE_1%ROWTYPE INDEX BY PLS_INTEGER;
TAB_I T_TABLE;
TAB_U T_TABLE;
--..more code
BEGIN
 SELECT COUNT(*) INTO rec_exist FROM TABLE_1 where COL_1 = ID;
EXCEPTION
 WHEN NO DATA FOUND THEN
   rec_exist := 0;
END;
--.... more code
-- COL1 is PK
IF rec_exist = 0 THEN
 TAB_I(IDX_I).COL1 = col1;
 TAB_I(IDX_I).COL2 = col2;
 IDX_I = IDX_I+ 1;
ELSE
 TAB_U(IDX_U).COL1 = col1;
 TAB_U(IDX_U).COL2 = col2;
 IDX_U = IDX_U+ 1;
END IF:
```

I send these table to insert/update after every 1000 records.

Now the question is, that imagine I receive a record whcih doesn't exist already in table_1. I decide to put it in tab_i array. I receive the another record update for this record. Since it is not in table, i will decide to put in tab_i, which will then give me a problem when i insert it in forall loop.

Now if my forall loop is like

FORALL .. 
  INSERT

FORALL .. 
  UPDATE

COMMIT;

If, I update the record as part of "update" statement which is not in table yet but was insert in table as part of forall above it, would that update work ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MERGE with FORALL - not supported, unless something has changed recently (12c perhaps?).  The reasoning behind this is that a MERGE statement implicitly performs the same action as a FORALL because the USING clause can select multiple values from a variety of sources, including PL/SQL collections.  I've never tried this
 but I've seen examples, including [this AskTom posting](http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11%3a%3a%3a%3a%3aP11_QUESTION_ID:8912264456901).

If you do the INSERTs before the UPDATEs, the INSERTed values will be visible when the UPDATEs are performed.

Share and enjoy.